# Story where colony ship is actually artificial intelligence lab which creates intelligence deciding how crew worship it

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

Ship is launched for stated purpose of colonization but one crew member is attempting to create artificial intelligence.  As story develops although outfitted for colonization there are indications it is actually artificial intelligence lab sent into deep space to isolate experiment from Earth as previous attempts have either failed drastically/horribly or vanished/disappeared without trace.

I remember one instance where crew asked question of developing AI about life which causes it to dissect several colonists in cold storage in attempt to answer question.

Comment: What language was it in, when was it written (approx.), was it short, part of an anthology, a novel?

Comment: Makes me think of Frank Herbert's series with The Jesus Incident and others

Comment: @Andrew Yes, _The Jesus Incident_ is a sequel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is probably [*Destination: Void*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2253) by Frank Herbert.  A fake colonization mission whose true purpose is to create artificial intelligence is a definite match.

Quoting from the [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destination:_Void) on Wikipedia:

> The current project is being run on the moon, and the book tells the story of **the seventh attempt in a series** of experiments to create an artificial consciousness. These clones are kept isolated and raised to believe that they will be the **crew of a spaceship that will colonize a planet** in the Tau Ceti solar system (Tau Ceti has no habitable planet; its choice—should they manage to reach it—is part of the planned frustration of the crew). The spaceship will take hundreds of years to reach the system and the crew will spend most of their time in hibernation. Along with the crew of six, **the ship carries thousands of other clones in hibernation**, intended to populate the new colony and, if necessary, provide replacements for any crew members who die along the way.
>
> The crew are just caretakers: the ship is controlled by a disembodied human brain, called "Organic Mental Core" or "OMC", that runs the complex operations of the vessel and keeps it moving in space. But the first two OMCs (Myrtle and Little Joe) become catatonic, while **the third OMC goes insane and kills two** of the umbilicus crew members. The crew are left with only one choice: to **build an artificial consciousness that will enable the ship to continue**. The crew knows that if they attempt to turn back they will be ordered to abort (self destruct).

The worship bit is from the stinger at the end of the book where, the clones having created a true artificial consciousness, the godlike intelligence demands that the clones decide how they will "WorShip" it.

Comment: I agree that this is the correct answer. (Popped into my head as soon as I saw the title of this question.) Some years ago, I finally got around to reading that book. I found I had to force myself to keep going until I finished. It just didn't grab me the way *Dune* did. On the other hand, I did feel that having Ship tell them "you will WorShip me" in the final paragraph was a memorable cliffhanger ending.

Comment: Sounds correct.  Frank Herbert were among the authors I collected.  The detailed description dredged more from memory.  Thnx.  Believe U got it.

Comment: @Lorendiac There were sequels, but not as gripping.